# Custom header for excel in penatho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am looking for customizing header using Pentaho. I have a sample excel file. which I have attached below

[image]

For integrating with postgres I played with `excel input` get the fields and mapped with postgres.After following this steps I wanted to extract data from postgres and make an another excel file with there data type in the excel header. The required format I attached below

[image]

**Note**

1 row - `Student` is the name of the sheet

2 row - `Datatype`

3 row - `Column name`

**Updated**

getting datatype I ran this query

`select table_name, column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where 
table_catalog='database name' and table_name='table name'`